# Is there a way to get rid of this weird line from a mirrored mesh?

Tags: mirror

There is a strange looking weird opening line when I mirror a mesh.

It normally happens if I extrude the right or left part of the mesh.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### The line comes from the mesh intersecting itself.

You've just moved those vertices too far one way. To solve it, either move them away from the center manually, or turn up the *Merge Distance* on the modifier a tiny bit. To make sure it doesn't happen again, turn on *Clipping* in the modifier.

Comment: Increasing the merge distance does kinda help.
But wdym by 'either move them away from the center manually'.

Comment: If you hide the Mirror modifier and look at your scene from the Front Orthographic view you'll see that some of your vertices have been moved too far along the X...so when the mesh is mirrored, both mirrored copies intersect each other by a small amount. (Mirror just flips the mesh along the chosen axis.) And don't turn Clipping on until you've resolved it...it can lead to weird problems.

Comment: @SamuelSullins Why not turn _Clipping_ on until he resolved it? If it's turned on he could easily move all vertices in the central area manuall a little bit +X, then move again a bit -X and all are aligned in the middle.

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann you're right, having it on might be better. I said it because it can get quite confusing if you're not used to using *Clipping*--you might get odd behavior like not being able to move vertices and not know why. (It's happened to me a few times.)